# The setOnItemLongClickListener in GridView is not clickable

Tags: android, android-gridview, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have tried all the suggestions I could find on S.O., and I was able to use this exact code successfully on a `ListView` of mine, but for some reason I can't set a long click listener on my `GridView`. I log inside the method `setupGridViewListener();` and it does not even run, yet I have my method inside `onCreateView()`. Don't know why it won't work. The alert dialog should pop up once long-clicked, but it doesn't. Method is at bottom of my class.

**UPDATE:**

I did not mention that my `onClickListener` does work fine. So I can at least do a single click, and this displays my activity. But, that code is in my adapter, so maybe they should be together in the same class? I am including my adapter and my 2 `xml`s below.

**UPDATE 2**
I discovered several things that were worth mentioning, even after I got my code working again. First of all, putting my click listeners into my adapter was a mistake. It slowed things down HUGELY... so much so, I was frantic about finding a way to get things on another thread. But in the end, I did not need to. I realized that I could actually get both of my click listeners into my `PhotoTab.java` class. This immediately made it faster (back to normal). But another curious thing, the IDE would not let me use `OnClickListener`, but insisted I go back to `OnItemClickListener`. So once I changed those back, everything worked again. So the listeners ended up being on my `GridView` variables, e.g. `gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}` not my `ImageView` item variables. Perhaps this is what made things faster? There is one `GridView`, but 24 `ImageView`s (`GridView` cells). But that is just a guess. I have updated my code to the current, working code. Except I'm still working on the long click code, so that's not right yet. The dialog alert works though, and each item in the `GridView` is clickable.

**PhotoTab.java**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection.phototab;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> adapter;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    private String[] allSDCardFiles = null;

    PhotoGridItem photoGridItem;

    public PhotoTab() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);

        // this null check won't instantiate again if it was already
//        if(adapter == null)
        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item);

        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // load contents of SD card
        loadSDCard();

        // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - allSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
            adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        }

        //Convert the bitmap to byte array, so can pass through intent
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        this.byteArray = byteArray;

        setupGridViewListener();

        return v;
    }


    public void loadSDCard() {

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File cutePhotosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Cute Photos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotosDir.listFiles();

            for (File singleFile : files) {

                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                // this method makes size small for the view (to save memory)
                bitmap = decodeImageBitmap(filePath, 270, 270);
                photoGridItem = new PhotoGridItem(bitmap);
                // Check if this is a new bitmap file
                adapter.add(photoGridItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // get number of files in Cute Photos directory
        allSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];

    }



    private void setupGridViewListener(){
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                    View item, int pos, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoViewerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("photo", byteArray);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });

        // to delete a photo item
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                           final int pos, long id) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .setMessage("Delete this cute photo?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // delete from ArrayList first
//                                PhotoTab.photoList.remove(position);

                                // get file name then delete it from SD card
                                File cutePhotosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CutePhotos/" + photoGridItem);
                                cutePhotosDir.delete();


                                // after each item delete, must refresh load so can delete again
//                                photoTab.loadSDCard();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // next 2 methods scale the bitmap image to a better size (so not huge)
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeImageBitmap(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {


        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }
}
```

**GridViewPhotoAdapter**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection.phototab;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
// package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
 */
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int position;

    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        this.position = position;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        // gets position of whichever photo you click on in the GridView
        final PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (photoGridItem != null) {
            Bitmap bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(270, 270));
        }


        return row;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

**photo_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2198bb">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/photo_grid"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**photo_grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photo_grid_view"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi I review your code, you want to delete the photo on long click of grid view item. You have single click that work fine, becz that you implemented inside the image click. I would suggested instead of try to catch the grid view long click yo can used the image view long click listener. :)

Comment: Thanks Bhavdip, another poster suggested that and it worked! :)

Comment: @Noni, I like your comments on the mistake on setting listeners in the Adapter. That seems normal (what you did previously) and I have done so for ListView, not GridView. Google has recommended listeners in the Adapter for ListView. I did not know using GridView can be so different. Now that you set listeners outside the Adapter, I suspect your current technique will take up more memory but maybe not much.

Comment: Yeah, it was a surprising discovery. It's possible I should still put my image loading process into an `AsyncTask` or another type of `Thread`, but it showed significant change when I put everything in the `PhotoTab.java` class, instead of the adapter class. Thanks for your additional insight though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package com.example.slideanim;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyGridAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        holder.imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(activity, "got", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post you row item xml for better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code. Btw, what is going on in your code? I don't understand your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks, I am trying to do that now. Getting lot of errors. :( But good to know you think that is the problem. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I added long click listener to adapter class. have a look on it.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. I was somehow importing the `AdapterView.onItemClickListener` versions, instead of `View.onClickListener`, and it was giving me errors all over the place. Android Studio doesn't always update your imports, so I'm really glad you showed me the right one!! Still can't get the delete of my file to work, but that's another issue. I got both click listeners in my adapter class, no small feat! And my long click pops up the dialog alert, like it should. Thanks to you. :) Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to either use click and long click for the imageview, or both on the gridview item.

If you want on imageview, do not setup the GridViewListener and try this in your adapter:

```
holder.imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //your code
        return true;
    }
});

holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context, PhotoViewerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("photo", byteArray);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! Another poster helped with this. :)

Comment: That's great! Didn't see the answer before I posted :).

Comment: Works great in the adapter. But how would you do it if you wanted this inside the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

-First of all check if any **Views** In your gridview are *Focusable* or *Clickable* or not make them ***False*** and then check your log again
-Let me inform if further issue exist
-THanks

Comment: The only thing I have, per a S.O. suggestion, is this: `gridView.setLongClickable(true);` But it didn't work without it, so I don't think that's it. I have only 1 `ImageView` as part of my custom `GridView` setup, but nothing in either `xml` layouts have focusable or clickable.

Comment: Check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931177/gridview-setonitemclicklistener-is-not-working  ImageViews can also intercept the clicks